# Voice Recognition in Python not working?

Tags: python, api, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, voice

```
import speech_recognition as sr


# obtain audio from the microphone


r = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")

audio = r.listen(source)

BING_KEY = ""  #API KEY HERE

try:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY))


except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition could not understand audio")


except sr.RequestError as e:

   print("Could not request results from Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

########################################################################################################

voiceLine = r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY)

if r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY) == "Hello":
    print("big nerd")

#### if voiceLine == "Hello":
####   print("big nerd")
```

The problem seems to be with the voiceline not acting like a normal string in "if" statements... (I'm farely new to python so please go easy on me :c) I am also aware that the indents are not in the right place, I don't know how to use this site, kms.

Comment: The case probably matters, it should be hello, not Hello

Comment: Could you explain in more Detail, what actually your Problem? What get you back from `r.recognize_bing()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this and it worked:

    faudio = r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY)

    if faudio.strip() == "whatever":
        do something...
```

Comment: I tried to count the len() of the response, in my case i use Google Cloud Speech, and i noticed a bunch of white spaces on the returning string, so just doing strip(), should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using external or Bluetooth microphone, you may need to install extra python package:

```
!pip install pyaudio
```

Then import the package in your code without changing anything, but you can check for the list of supported mics in your pc

```
import pyaudio
# check the list of microphones
sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
```

for a complete tutorial on speech recognition, it worth checking this website:
https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/